# Free Pascal keep numbers in array

Tags: arrays, numbers, pascal

i don't know how to do this: 
I want to do a program in pascal in which the user have to insert 90 numbers introduced by console and separated by a blank and keep them in a bidimensional array (10x9). Anyone knows how to implement this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to go get the code from one of your two other (now closed) questions, and put it in this one so people know what you've tried so far. (Edit it, using the `edit` link right below the tags, and paste the code in, which is what you should have done instead of duplicating it twice.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var the_array:array[1..10] of array[1..9] of integer;
var i:integer; var j:integer;
...
i:=1; j:=1;
while i<=10 do begin
    while j<=9 do begin
        read(the_array[i,j]);
        inc(j);
    end;
    j:=1;
    inc(i);
end;
```

You just use two indices to iterate through an array while filling it from calling read().

Comment: If you want a short implementation (i like that), why not define `area[1..10,1..9]` instead? Note that this code does not allow space-limited numbers.. You wouldn't want to enter 90 numbers like this (well, not space delimited either) :)

Comment: How come this does not allow space-limited numbers? read() stops at whitespace, while readln() stops only at carriage returns. So, given an input like "1 3 5 2 3" this string will get parsed into 5 numbers. And for short definition, yes, it's just I'm now into Actionscript, where double dimension arrays can't be declared and addressed with [a,b] but only with [a][b], so I overcompensated.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you use FreePascal, so you can make use of SScanF here.

This program lets you enter some lines of numbers that are separated by spaces.
After it's done, it prints the numbers.

I would not ever hand something like this over to end users though. Why not provide a graphical user interface instead?

```
program Project1;
uses
  SysUtils;

const
  Lines = 10;

type
  TNumberArray = array[0..Lines-1,0..9] of integer;

procedure GetNumbers(var nums:TNumberArray);
var Line:Integer; s:String;
begin
  for Line := Low(nums) to high(nums) do
  begin
    Write('Enter line ',Line, ': ');
    ReadLn(S);
    SScanf(s,'%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d',
      [
        @nums[Line,0],
        @nums[Line,1],
        @nums[Line,2],
        @nums[Line,3],
        @nums[Line,4],
        @nums[Line,5],
        @nums[Line,6],
        @nums[Line,7],
        @nums[Line,8],
        @nums[Line,9]
      ]
    );
  end;
end;

procedure ShowNumbers(nums:TNumberArray);
var Line,Col:Integer;
begin
  for Line := Low(nums) to high(nums) do
  begin
    for Col:=Low(nums[Line]) to High(nums[Line]) do
      Write(nums[Line,Col], ' ');
    WriteLn;
  end;
end;

var
  Numbers: TNumberArray;


begin
  WriteLn('Enter 10 numbers');

  GetNumbers(Numbers);
  ShowNumbers(Numbers);

  WriteLn('Done. Press a key to continue.');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

It's cleaner to parse the line using a TStringList, so that you don't have to hard-code the number of columns, but this should work.